# How to reference a C++ library project from a .NET one in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 projects

- A C++ library
- A .NET app that uses the above

When I want to run the .NET app I have to build the C++ library manually and copy the binary to the .NET app output folder, so it can Work.

How to automate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you've got a solution with both projects.  Right-click the C++ project, Properties, Configuration Properties, General.  Change the Output Directory setting to

> $(SolutionDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)

Repeat for the Release configuration (upper left combo).  That ensures the C++ build is using the same folder naming strategy as the .NET build (bin\Debug and bin\Release).

Now right-click the .NET project, Project Dependencies and tick the C++ project.  That ensures that the C++ project gets built first and that the build output gets copied to your .NET build folder.

Comment: That's right, that changed in VS2010.  The posted version is for earlier releases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use post-build event, which can be found in Build events under project properties.
You can write commands to compile your C++ prjects using MSBuild if needed and copy resulting dll to needed directory.

For example
copy ..\..\include\crash_rpt\bin\dbghelp\dbghelp.dll ..\bin\debug

Comment: and how to make the .NET project to build the C++ project when required?

Comment: MSBuild has options to Build/Rebuild/Clean project. So you can Build your project in Pre-Build event and then copy it to the bin directory of your project. The C++ project will not be fully rebuilt every time if there is no changes

Answer (score 1):

You can make the output folder of both projects same folder. Then you do not need to copy.

Comment: and how to control build order? and how to make the .NET project to build the C++ project first?

Comment: Put both projects into same solution, then make .NET project dependent on C++ project. They will build in dependency order.